# Naming files based on csv dictionary in python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to rename multiple files based on a csv file. In the csv file there is 2 columns, Column A for the new file name that I would like to use for renaming, and Column B - the current file name. I've written some code to that reads the csv file into a dictionary which seems to work but the code I've written to actually rename the files does not seem to work. I am very new to python, thanks in advance for any help!

Csv file is structured like so:

```
A LADY WITH A SPOON.NEW.ORGANIC.MP4, GGI9AE44.MP4
LADIES BELLY.BL REGULARIS.20 YEARS. MOST SOLD YOGURT IN CANADA_1.mp4, FNJ17A5I.MP4
LADIES BELLY.BL REGULARIS.20 YEARS. MOST SOLD YOGURT IN CANADA_2.mp4, FNJ17A5I.MP4
PRODUCT BOTTLES.LIVE & ACTIVE PROBIOTICS.PROBIOTIC CHALLENGE.mp4, GKJ174GV.MP4
```

Code:

```
import csv
import os

# make an empty dictionary which will hold the keys
keys = {}

#open file
with open('C:/TestNamingFiles.csv','r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',', quotechar='"')
# build a dictionary with the associated ids
        for rowDict in reader:
              keys[ rowDict[1] ] = rowDict[0]
              print(rowDict)
# renaming
for fileName in (os.listdir('.') & keys.keys()):
    if fileName in rowDict:
        os.rename(fileName, keys[fileName])
```

EDIT: This is the final code I ended up using to complete the tasks, in case anyone is interested. I created two folders, one for the original file to be stored and one for the new, renamed files (so that the original file would not get renamed and prevent the renaming of duplicate files). I also added the file path to each of these folders in my csv file.

```
import csv
import os
import shutil

# make an empty dictionary which will hold the keys
keys = {}

#open file
with open('C:/TestNamingFiles3.csv','r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',', quotechar='"')
# build a dictionary with the associated ids
        for rowDict in reader:
              keys[ rowDict[0] ] = rowDict[1]
              print(rowDict)
# renaming
for key, value in keys.items():
    print ("Copied", value, "as", key)
    # specifying that if the file exists then do not move into new files folder
    if not os.path.exists(key):
        shutil.copy(value, key)
```

Comment: use print() to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed - maybe it never runs `os.rename`

Comment: what do you expect with `os.listdir('.') & keys.keys()` ? It is not correct code. First: `&` is for bytes operations. Second: if you expect to create path with filename then it is not good idea. Better use only `for fileName in os.listdir('.'):`

Comment: Not a python expert but spaces in your csv after the comma might be the problem?

Comment: @furas `&` can also be used for key intersection, which it looks like the OP using for intersecting file names.

Comment: @RoadRunner now I see - it works only because there is `dict_keys`.

Comment: `rowDict` keeps only last value - you should skip `if fileName in rowDict:` because you already filter by `& keys.keys()`. Eventually you should check `if fileName in keys.keys():` if you don't use `& keys.keys()` And this can makes all problem. You would see this if you would use `print()` to display values in variables and to see which part of code is executed.

Comment: There are also two `FNJ17A5I.MP4`? How do you rename in this case?

Comment: if there are duplicate names, i want it to make a copy of the first instance of that current file name and then rename it to the corresponding new file name if that makes sense. I think i would need to use os copy? shutil.copy?